# Pug js custom filters

Tags: javascript, pug

I cant to use custom filter from https://pugjs.org/language/filters.html#custom-filters

```
options.filters = {
  'filtername': function (text, options) {
    if (options.addStart) text = 'Start\n' + text;
    if (options.addEnd)   text = text + '\nEnd';
    return text;
  }
};

p
  :filtername(addStart addEnd)
    Filter
    Body
```

and have error

```
Pug:2:3
1| options.filters = {
> 2| 'filtername': function (text, options) {
---------^
3| if (options.addStart) text = 'Start\n' + text;
4| if (options.addEnd) text = text + '\nEnd';
5| return text;

unexpected text "'filt"
```

https://codepen.io/umasterov/pen/oNZZjqr

Comment: You're supposed to put the options in you Pug render call inside JavaScript, not in the Pug template

Answer (score 0):

The `options.filters` configuration isn't meant to be placed in the Pug file. It's meant to be passed to the compiler in Node. As such, it won't be possible to run a custom Pug filter in a regular CodePen, since there's no way to pass options to the Pug compiler.

Comment: In which file need to type this code? I don't see this info in docs

Comment: What are you using to compile the Pug? Just the PugJS Node package? @IvanU

Comment: Yes, just pug js package @Sean

Comment: That should be the `options` object you pass to one of the compiler methods in Node: https://pugjs.org/api/reference.html#methods

Comment: So, what code should I write in what file? @Sean

Comment: @IvanU define the `options` object with the `object.filters` property, then pass it to the compiler method as shown in the link.

Comment: On the link page, there is no information about what exactly and in which file I need to write. So, how to pass it to the compiler method? @Sean

Comment: @IvanU In what file do you have `require('pug')`?